# Parsing Plain-text during Email Service

Tags: apex, class, apex-email-service

I have being trying to Parse this text properly for a couple days now. I cannot seem to figure out how to collect the text after **Traveller name** in the following Text:

> > ---------- Forwarded message --------- From: Mai Le Date: Thu, Sep 10, 2015 at 11:32 PM Subject: Inquiry from Mai Le: Sep 26 through 28 -
> >     VRBO.com #468160 To: , Congratulations, you have a new inquiry!
> >     [image: VRBO from HomeAway] [image: Our Family of Brands] Hello, Mai
> >     Le is interested in your property. Property #468160 Dates Available *
> >     Sep 26-28, 2015 * , 2 nights Guests 4 adults, 2 children Traveler name
> >     Mai Le Traveler email pmaitu@gmail.com **Traveler phone + CA 6138842305
> >     Inquiry from HomeAway.com** Total rental amount $448.00 including taxes
> >     and fees ------------------------------ * Message from Mai Le* Hello,
> >     I would like to finalize my booking. Please let me know the best
> >     number i can reach you for details. I have 5 adults and 2 small
> >     children. Mai ------------------------------ Respond in your dashboard
> >     Or, reply to this email Respond quickly to increase your chance of
> >     securing the booking. Looking for more inquiries? Listings with a
> >     quality score of 80% or greater get 15%* more demand! Follow the
> >     customized recommendations in your dashboard now. * Based on internal
> >     metrics taken from data on VRBO.com between December 1, 2014 and
> >     December 31, 2014 Download the HomeAway app so you can reply to
> >     travelers, send payment details, manage your calendar, and more on
> >     your mobile device. ------------------------------ [image: Facebook]
> >     [image: Twitter] © 2015 HomeAway.com, Inc. All rights reserved. VRBO
> >     and the VRBO logos are trademarks of HomeAway.com, Inc. HomeAway.com,
> >     Inc. is located at 1011 West Fifth Street, Suite 300, Austin, Texas,
> >     78703. This email was sent to inquiries@niagarasmartstays.com,alex@niagarasmartstays.com. View our
> >     Privacy Statement | Contact Us | Terms & Conditions

I need to search for Traveler name using Regex to collect "Mai Le", and paste that into the Lead.Name field on a new lead record. I'm not sure why this isn't working but here is my current regex formula.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile('(?m)(?i)^\\s*name(.*)');
Matcher pm = p.matcher( leadRecord.RichEmailText__c );

if( pm.matches() )
{
     leadRecord.Email_Guest_Name__c = pm.group(1);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your post you want to get the text that is between 'Traveler name' and 'Traveler email'.  This regex will create 3 capture groups.  The 2nd capture group will be the name of the traveler.

> (?mi)(traveler\s*name)(.*\s*)(traveler\s*email)

```
  string source = 'asdfsdf asdfsdf Traveler name Mai Le Traveler email asdfasf asdfsadf asdfsf ';

  Matcher m = Pattern.compile('(?mi)(traveler\\s*name)(.*\\s*)(traveler\\s*email)').matcher(source);
     if (m.find()){
        System.debug('Success');
        System.debug(m.group(0));
        System.debug(m.group(1));
        System.debug(m.group(2));
        System.debug(m.group(3));
     }
```

Comment: Thank you this has taken me very far in my project! Although when I try to retrieve the phone number in the same fashion,  it does not run as expected. Example: (?mi)(traveler\\s*phone)(.*\\d*)(inquiry\\s*from\\s*Homeaway\\.com). This regex captures everything between the 1st and 3rd capture groups (including "+ CA"). Should it not only capture numbers between the 1st and 3rd capture groups?

Comment: You need to account for the white space between the number and 'inquiry'.  Your expression will only match if there is no space 6138842305Inquiry